# Две грамматические основы

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, грамматика, грамматическая-основа

В каком предложении (предложениях) две грамматические основы (знаки
препинания не расставлены)?

1. Жанр элегии предполагает рассуждения о жизни и смерти воспоминания о былом и грусть о быстротечном счастье.
2. В лунную ночь развёртывалась перед нами вся ширь с лугами и холмами и было видно далеко окрест.
3. Темнеет и последний солнечный луч вскоре ускользнёт из комнаты.
4. Анастасии Ивановне свойственно было выражать себя не столько в словах сколько в делах и поступках.
5. Попробуйте вспомнить любой свой день минуту за минутой и вы убедитесь что если восстановить весь этот поток времени можно написать целую книгу.

В ответах 2, 3.
Но почему-то они упустили из  виду предложение 5.

Comment: Что именно повторяющиеся?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, 5-е предложение не включено в ответ, так как в нём не две, а минимум три основы (или даже четыре).

*Попробуйте вспомнить любой свой день минуту за минутой, и вы убедитесь, что, если восстановить весь этот поток времени, можно написать целую книгу.*

Основы:
*попробуйте вспомнить, вы убедитесь, восстановить* (в придаточном предложении), *можно написать*.